# Errorlevel is different

Tags: batch-file, find, findstr, errorlevel

I've been trying to write this batch script.  What I want it to do is open msinfo.exe, then using the wmic check the manufacturer & depending on the manufacturer it will open that manufacturers website.  Here's what I have written all ready without success:

```
@echo off

start %windir%\System32\msinfo32.exe

if exist c:\BIOS.txt (
      start c:\BIOS.txt
) else (
      wmic /output:c:\BIOS.txt bios get smbiosbiosversion
)

:asus

wmic /output:c:\Manufacturer.txt Computersystem get Manufacturer | FINDSTR "asus" > NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
      %programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" **place support site here**
      goto exit
) else (
      goto dell
)

:dell

wmic /output:c:\Manufacturer.txt Computersystem get Manufacturer | FINDSTR "dell" > NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
      "%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" **place support site here**
      goto exit
) else (
      goto gateway
)

:gateway

wmic /output:c:\Manufacturer.txt Computersystem get Manufacturer | FINDSTR "gateway" > NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
      "%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" **place support site here**
      goto exit
) else (
      goto hp
)

:hp

wmic /output:c:\Manufacturer.txt Computersystem get Manufacturer | FINDSTR "hewlett-packard" > NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
      "%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" **place support site here**
      goto exit
) else (
      goto lenovo
)

:lenovo

wmic /output:c:\Manufacturer.txt Computersystem get Manufacturer | FINDSTR "lenovo" > NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
      "%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" **place support site here**
      goto exit
) else (
      goto samsung
)

:samsung

wmic /output:c:\Manufacturer.txt Computersystem get Manufacturer | FINDSTR "samsung" > NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
      "%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" **place support site here**
      goto exit
) else (
      goto sony
)

:sony

wmic /output:c:\Manufacturer.txt Computersystem get Manufacturer | FINDSTR "sony" > NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
      "%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" **place support site here**
      goto exit
) else (
      goto toshiba
)

:toshiba

wmic /output:c:\Manufacturer.txt Computersystem get Manufacturer | FINDSTR "toshiba" > NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
      "%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" **place support site here**
      goto exit
) else (
      goto exit
)

:exit
```

Any help with making me understand would be greatly appreciated.  Everything I'm reading & trying just isn't getting me results.  I've read everything on here about errorlevel & I guess it's not making sense?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because you redirect the output you want to search by using FINDSTR to a file. So FINDSTR has nothing to search in.

Either remove the /output (if you don't need the file for something else) or do like this:

```
wmic /output:c:\Manufacturer.txt Computersystem get Manufacturer 
type C:\manufacturer.txt | FINDSTR "asus"
```

In the first line you get the output from wmic and have it sent to a file.
In the second line you take the freshly created file and send it to FINDSTR which then will search for the element you specified. After that you can test the errorlevel.

To improve your batch it perhaps would make sense to create the text files in a temporary directory and delete them before you run the batch again. Putting this at the top of the batch would be a good idea. So you can be sure that if wmic fails for some reason you don't process old data.